# What is the apparatus used to keep meat upright called?

Tags: equipment

My mother has this thing that we use to cook whole chickens with. It is a round tray with four holes in the sides. It then has two pieces of strong wire in the shape of an omega sign that clicks into the holes. You then put the whole bird on top. Basically sticking it up the chickens butt. This keeps your bird upright in the oven. For some reason having your chicken upright when you cook it makes a tremendous difference in taste.

We just called a rotisserie, but that does not seem to be it's name. After many years of faithful service the countless liters of gravy we ladle over countless chickens have rusted holes in the tray. So, I would like to know what is called so I can replace it.

Comment: I will get a picture on monday.

Comment: I have seen similar used for "Beer Can Chicken" where it has a place to hold a standard American beer can upright and then the chicken fits over the can. Can be used without a beer can, I presume. Maybe searching for *beer can chicken*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe an upright/vertical chicken roaster/rack is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes. Searching “upright chicken roaster” gets all sorts.